# PushPlugin - PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

On this URL: http://leuq.app.ovoweb.net/#/ I am trying to get PhoneGap - PushPlugin to work.

It works fine on iOS. But on Android it stucks on registering Android device. When running the Ripple emulator, it says Cordova is not defined. But why is it then working in iOS? What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the phonegap.js file is not provided, if you are using phonegapbuild you must just include a link to this file. But if you're compiling in your computer the file must be included

Comment: I have now tested it on 2 real Android devices and it is still not working. phonegap.js is "injected" according to the Phonegap build APIs. But I still not know why this is not working.